# when the method OnUnregistered() will be invoked in GCMIntentService Class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I have successfully implemented the `GCM` framework for push notification in my android application.But I am little bit confused about the function overridden in `GcmIntentService` Class by Google.

```
@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {

//Do whatever you want
```

}

When this method will get invoked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be called after you have unregistered from the GCM servers using the [GCMRegistrar.unregister() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html#unregister%28android.content.Context%29).

As documented here in the [GCMBaseIntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService.html#onUnregistered%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%29) docs:

> Called after a device has been unregistered.

You should also take a look at the [How Unregistration Works](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#unreg) documentation as it describes the two ways a device will be unregistered: manually and automatically.

Comment: but as of now i think the automatic functionality will not work because android doesn't provide an uninstall callback. am i right ?

Comment: It will, but only after you send multiple messages. Because there is no uninstall callback GCM will only know that your app has been uninstalled when it tries to deliver it a message. Then when your server attempts to send another message, GCM will let your server know that the app has been uninstalled from that one device. And your server handles it. In that situation the unregistered callback is not called.

Answer (score 3):

From the official java doc:

> To unregister from GCM, do the following:

```
Intent unregIntent = new
Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER");
 unregIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new
 Intent(), 0)); 
 startService(unregIntent);
```

> Similar to the registration
>        request, this intent is sent asynchronously, and the response comes as
>        a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION intent.

One use case might be to call web service on your server so that it can remove the device from its list of registered devices.

Comment: I got your point and i already had an idea about that but my question is when this thing will be executed.whether On uninstalling the application or automatically becuse of application out of network when??

Comment: oh sorry for missing that... have you tried unregistered from the GCM service. As per doc it should be called when device unregistered from the GCM service so that one can Notify 3rd-party server about the unregistered ID...

Comment: It will not be called when you uninstall, it's a callback that is triggered when you unregister from the GCM servers.

Comment: when can one unregister from GCM server. What is the need of un-registering from GCM.

Comment: @pyus13 See my response above. You can unregister from the GCM servers whenever you want. You might want to give your users a pref to do it, or you could do it based on any other condition. Unregistering from GCM would be to stop receiving messages.

Answer (score 2):

For unregistering android device from GCM, add this line where you want to unregister in the code

```
GCMRegistrar.unregister(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onUnregistered(Context context, String regId):
```

#### Called after the device has been unregistered from GCM. Typically, you should send the regid to the server so it unregisters the device.

Found out that you can unregistered before app is about to get uninstalled. Dunno but hope so that's the one way

#### Calling Activity before the app is about to get uninstalled, Add Activity with below Intent-filters::

```
 <activity
    android:name=".UninstallIntentActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="package" android:pathPattern="com.testpack.yourapp" />
    </intent-filter>



</activity>
```

Inside that Activity you can call your ::

```
 onUnregistered(Context context, String regId):
```

get unregistered that device. Hope there must be some better way for these.

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution which i expect from Android developer site itself actually the function should automatically called when application is getting uninstalled as per Google's description on developer's site However, this process does not happens right away, as Android does not provide an uninstall callback. please check the link mentioned below :

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#unreg

Thanks to all for support.

Comment: That is not technically correct if you check the docs. That function will not be called in that situation because the app will already be uninstalled, therefore no callback can be triggered. The app will unregistered from GCM yes, but the callback you asked about will not be called.

Comment: @selsine please go through the link i have shared once the Google also saying the same they are thing about to do like this but as of now its not happening and that is why i was confused.

Comment: can the person who downvoted the answer tell me why it is down voted so i can improve my answer.

Comment: The error in this answer is that the question was about when the onUnregistered() callback method will be called. The method is called when the app unregisters from GCM using the unregister() method. But this will not happen when the app is uninstalled, if that makes sense.

Comment: @selsine actually that i already know because the name itself saying that thing but i was thinking that this will call automatically when application will get uinstalled and i had written a log in the function but the loag was not appear so i was confused.. but thanks for your help .